# Шрифты в Python

Tags: python

Как получить список шрифтов, которые доступны в системе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [tkFont.families](http://pydoc.org/2.3.3/tkFont.html)

```
import Tkinter
import tkFont

root = Tkinter.Tk()
list_fonts = list(tkFont.families())
```

С помощью [pygame.font.get_fonts](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html)

> Возвращает список всех шрифтов, доступных в системе. Имена шрифтов будет установлена ​​в нижний регистр, все пробелы и знаки препинания удалены. Это работает на многих системах, но некоторые из них будут возвращать пустой список, если они не смогут найти шрифты.